# Inherited class property `DisplayAttribute` not being overridden?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, overriding, data-annotations

I have a base class that inherits properties from another base class, as well as adds a new one, like so:

```
public class DataSourceWithIntervalBase : DataSourceBase
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Interval")]
    public virtual string Interval1 { get; set; }
}
```

There's nothing special about `DataSourceBase`, it just has a few properties I need to allow users to edit.

`DataSourceWithIntervalBase`, however, further becomes inherited by other classes. They're all very similar, except for their `Display` attributes, for UI purposes.

Here's one of those classes, for example:

```
public class SqlServerDataSource : DataSourceWithIntervalBase
{
    public SqlServerDataSource()
    {
        FeedType = FeedType.SqlServer;
    }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Connection String")]
    public override string Url { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Table Name")]
    public override string Interval1 { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that I'm overriding 2 properties here. `Url`, found in `DataSourceBase`, and `Interval1`, found in `DataSourceWithIntervalBase`.

Nothing seems to break when using this inheritance. It does work. However, the `Display` attribute does not get overridden. The `Url` of `DataSourceBase` doesn't actually have one, but even still it does not get accounted for when used in an editor View. The `Interval1` property gets labeled as the following:

```
Interval
```

So how can I force my inheriting classes to properly override the `Display` attribute of my base classes?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the usage of `DataSourceWithIntervalBase`, you don't actually need the `[Display]` attribute there. It doesn't solve the inheritance problem, but it solves your problem.

Comment: Then that means there is another base class along the way specifying it. The attribute will be applied when it is first contacted (i.e. on the first class it appears on). This also means that your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is best practice, but it works.

If no other answers can improve upon / circumvent this solution, I'll stick with this, and hope it helps somebody else.

I used a `switch` statement on the types of `DataSource` View Models and casted the appropriate type to access its `DisplayAttribute` directly, like so:

```
@switch (Model.FeedType) // switch to cast correct Model Type in order to access proper DisplayAttribute for Interval1
{
    case Model.FeedType.RSS:
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.XML:
    @Html.LabelFor(m => ((XmlDataSource)m).Interval1)
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.SqlServer:
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.Excel2003:
    @Html.LabelFor(m => ((Excel2003DataSource)m).Interval1)
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.InterLinkFeeder:
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.Atom:
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.Excel2007:
    @Html.LabelFor(m => ((Excel2007DataSource)m).Interval1)
        break;
    case Model.FeedType.JSON:
    @Html.LabelFor(m => ((JsonDataSource)m).Interval1)
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Keep in mind I skipped various types because this `switch` statement is in an `EditorTemplate` that is not going to be used for those types.

You can easily work this solution to your particular situation.